# Defaulting a variable to current window location if environment variable is not set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, docker, environment-variables

I am trying to dockerize a javascript project. The UI project reads its API endpoint from an endpoint that is set as an environment variable of the container at runtime

The way I parse this environment variables is by setting as foolows

```
apiUrl: 'http://'+JSON.parse($envVariable).endpoints.backend + ':80'
```

There is a shell script that replaces the value of `$envVariable` with the api endpoint url based on envsubst (https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html)

Now,

This project when not run as a container should read its api endpoint from its current location that is ,

```
'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080'
```

How do I implement the logic so that if the environment variable is set only then use the first parse implementation or else default to the window location? The challenge being I cant read env variable from the browser

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

#Install Node
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install nodejs -y
RUN apt-get install nodejs-legacy -y
RUN apt-get install npm -y
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10

# Install packages for envsubst
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y --force-yes && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gettext-base


# Create app directory 
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# cache package.json and node_modules provide dependencies
COPY dist dist
COPY envcombined.js dist/scripts/envcombined.js
COPY package.json package.json
RUN mkdir dist/node_modules
COPY node_modules dist/node_modules

# Substitute dependencies from environment variables
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 8000
```

And the entrypoint script

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf /usr/src/app/dist/scripts/combined.js
envsubst \$envVariable < "/usr/src/app/dist/scripts/envcombined.js" > "/usr/src/app/dist/scripts/combined.js"
cp package.json /usr/src/app/dist/
cd /usr/src/app/dist/
exec npm start
```

I can have the following declaration so the apiEndpoint is evaluated to window location

```
var $EnvVar = '{"endpoints":{"api":"http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080"}}'


apiUrl :JSON.parse($EnvVar).endpoints.api;
```

Now the shell script should only replace the second occurence of the $EnvVar

Answer (score 0):

One sort of hacky way to achieve this is to create a custom variable:

```
customApiUrl = ('$envVariable'.length ? 'http://'+JSON.parse($envVariable).endpoints.backend + ':80' : 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080')
```

and use it like this:

```
apiUrl: customApiUrl
```

When you run `envsubst`, this is what it will result into:

```
/tmp $ cat a.js
customApiUrl = ('$envVariable'.length ? 'http://'+JSON.parse($envVariable).endpoints.backend + ':80' : 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080')

# Without the envVariable set
/tmp $ envVariable= envsubst \$envVariable < a.js
customApiUrl = (''.length ? 'http://'+JSON.parse().endpoints.backend + ':80' : 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080')

# With the envVariable set
/tmp $ envVariable='decodeMe' envsubst \$envVariable < a.js
customApiUrl = ('decodeMe'.length ? 'http://'+JSON.parse(decodeMe).endpoints.backend + ':80' : 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080')
```

If you plan to use the `$EnvVar` declaration as mentioned in the question, you can also replace the second occurrence of `$EnvVar` in the script conditionally:

```
/tmp $ cat b.js
var $EnvVar = '{"endpoints":{"api":"http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080"}}'    
apiUrl :JSON.parse($EnvVar).endpoints.api;

/tmp $ EnvVar=''
/tmp $ [ ! -z "$EnvVar" ] && sed  "0,/EnvVar/! s/EnvVar/$EnvVar/" -i b.js
/tmp $ cat b.js # No change
var $EnvVar = '{"endpoints":{"api":"http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080"}}'    
apiUrl :JSON.parse($EnvVar).endpoints.api;


/tmp $ EnvVar='my_variable'                                                                                                                                                                                    
/tmp $ [ ! -z "$EnvVar" ] && sed  "0,/EnvVar/! s/EnvVar/$EnvVar/" -i b.js
/tmp $ cat b.js # variable got substituted in the second occurrence 
var $EnvVar = '{"endpoints":{"api":"http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080"}}'    
apiUrl :JSON.parse($my_variable).endpoints.api;
```

And in the shell script you would use it as:

```
if [ ! -z "$EnvVar" ] 
then
   sed "0,/EnvVar/! s/EnvVar/$EnvVar/" "/usr/src/app/dist/scripts/envcombined.js" > "/usr/src/app/dist/scripts/combined.js"
else
   cp "/usr/src/app/dist/scripts/envcombined.js" "/usr/src/app/dist/scripts/combined.js"
fi
```

Or, you could replace the already existing file directly:

```
[ ! -z "$EnvVar" ] && sed  "0,/EnvVar/! s/EnvVar/$EnvVar/" -i "/usr/src/app/dist/scripts/combined.js"
```

Comment: umm... I made a little modification and I'll make the dit, but I feel that the shell script should take care of the replacement rather than messing too much with app code

Comment: I've made the dit

Comment: Hi NEhal, trying to understand the script, where is it making the conditionale replacement using envsubst? I do not know the value of the env varible and its read only at docker run for the container

Comment: @user_mda I don't use envsubst in the second part. sed -i will take care of the replacement in place, if the environment variable is present.

Comment: I cannot define the env variable before hand, thats part of the docer run command only available at runtime

Comment: @user_mda Yes, you need to remove the envsubst line and replace it with the sed one inside the script.

Comment: @user_mda I am defining the variable in the answer just to show you different scenarios. I am not asking you to define it yourself.

Comment: Got it, I have not really written shell scripts before, so its a little hardto understand. What does [ ! -z "$EnvVar" ]  do?

Comment: Open the man page for bash and read the section on conditional expressions.

Comment: its not working for me, I dont want the variable to be replaced with a dollar sign. I just tested out with a simpler file and its replacing all occurences of the variable